# removeClass if href != hashtag

Tags: jquery, url, scroll, removeclass, hashtag

I have a code that makes my URL go like this `www.mypage.com#div1` to `www.mypage.com#div2` when I scroll down the page. To get my menu items highlighted as I scroll down the page, I've written this code which works fine:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".menu a").each(function() {
        if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        } else {
            //Something here?
        }
    });
});
```

But the thing is that I want to remove the "active"-class again. I tried putting all sorts of things in the "else"-section, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Tina

Comment: Did you try `$(this).removeClass("active");`?

Comment: it seems `this.href == window.location.href` is always false because as you mentioned your absolute url, beacause `href="#div1" !== window.location.href` this should be `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with [attribute-equals-selector/](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass('active');
  });
```

Comment: +1 from me, maybe add a selector for `location.pathname + location.hash` to cover relative URLs?

Comment: I'm new here so I don't know how to do this, but your post was right when I changed window.location.href to window.location.hash, like this: $(window).scroll(function() {
 $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass('active');
});

Answer (score 0):

This should work: 
First of all remove the active class and then assign it to an appropriate div

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
           $(".menu a").each(function() {
               $(".active").removeClass("active");  
               if (this.href == window.location.href) {

                   $(this).addClass("active");
               } 
           });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your if condition to this and see if it solves:

```
if (this.href == window.location.hash) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
} else {
    $('.active').removeClass("active");
}
```